# Save Excel file via web page using java script

Tags: javascript, html, excel

```
var myApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
                myApp.visible = true;
                var myWorkbook;             
            var xlCellTypeLastCell = 11;
                myObject = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
                    if(myObject.FileExists("xyz.xlsx")){
                myWorkbook = myApp.Workbooks.Open("xyz.xlsx");
                                }
                else{

                    myWorkbook=myApp.Workbooks.Add();
                    }

                var myWorksheet = myWorkbook.Worksheets(1);

                myWorksheet.Activate;

                objRange = myWorksheet.UsedRange;

                objRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Activate ;

                newRow = myApp.ActiveCell.Row + 1;

                strNewCell = "A" + newRow;

                myApp.Range(strNewCell).Activate;

                myWorksheet.Cells(newRow,1).value=document.getElementById("table1").rows[1].cells.item(0).innerHTML;                myWorksheet.Cells(newRow,2).value=document.getElementById("table1").rows[1].cells.item(4).innerHTML;    
        myWorksheet.Cells(newRow,3).value=document.getElementById("table1").rows[1].cells.item(5).innerHTML;

                myWorkbook.SaveAs("xyz.xlsx");

                myApp.Quit();
```

The above code saves the excel for the first time, in the second loop it pops the window asking to save manually, i am trying to save the file automatically without manual intervention.

Comment: You can't. You need to present the user with the save dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch off display alerts temporarily. This is in VBA. Change it to use myApp

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
' save here
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

The DisplayAlerts documentation is short and worth reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839782.aspx

Comment: Happy to help. If a proposed answer meets your requirements, it is the usual practice to up vote it and mark it as accepted.